# Maven using windows authentication automatically

Tags: maven

All,
I am aware that providing a proxy entry for `maven` can enable using proxy authentication.
My question is "Is it possible to enable proxy authentication without providing the proxy entries in the `settings.xml` file"?

I want to avoid providing clear text user id passwords in an `XML` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maven password encryption](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: This is absolutely not the answer he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maven has no support for transparent Kerberos support nor does it retrieve the proxy settings thru the JVM out of Windows. This means that you have to provide both proxy and your credentials. You should consider setting up a Nexus instance in your environment.

Comment: could you provide me a link to the Nexus setup? I am sorry I am not aware of Nexus. Is it http://nexus.sonatype.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, this is Nexus. All of your devs will be served by Nexus rather than accessing repos directly. It improved performance here greatly.